# Charles Request "Text" tab

Tags: ruby, networking, charles-proxy

I've been sniffing some traffic and trying to recreate the requests in my own automated script. I'm doing this in Ruby using the RestClient (https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

In the requests I'm sniffing I see it sending a token in the "Text" tab. The request is a POST request, and I'm trying to recreate it in Ruby. I can send the headers and all the parameters fine, but am not sure what that "Text" tab is or how to send what I see in that tab in my Ruby POST request.

Any Charles and Networking masters out there know what this is and how I can send it with a Ruby request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "text" tab is the payload of the request. If you look at the "Raw" tab, the text is everything after the blank line, including this in my request fixed my issue.